# Using event to wake an async long running job

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, async-await

I have a class (`Class A`) that is responsible for running an async job in the background that looks like this:

```
public async void DoJob()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var thingToDo = this.getNextThing();

        if (thingToDo != null)
        {
            try
            {
                await this.performAction(thingToDo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // file logging of error.
                // then wait a certain period.
                await Task.Delay(someInterval);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Gets the interval that should be awaited until there is a 
            // thingToDo available.
            var waitInterval = this.getWaitUntilNextThingAvailable();

            // if there such an interval then wait for it.
            if (waitInterval != null)
            {
                await Task.Delay(waitInterval.Value);
            }
            // else (basically when there is nothing to be done by this job) 
            // use an AsyncManualResetEvent to wait until its set.
            else
            {
                await this.waitHandle.WaitAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am basically interested in the last `else` block - the one where I use an `AsyncManualResetEvent` (provided by the [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/) library)

I use an event provided by another class (`Class B`) to set the `waitHandle`. This is how the subscription looks like (note that this method is in `Class B`)

```
private event Action ChangeOccurred;

public void Attach(Action action)
{
   this.ChangeOccurred += action;
}
```

And now onto my question : I use `ChangeOccurred?.Invoke()` to set the `waitHandle` such that `Class A` can be notified that there is something to do and continue performing things in the background.

Is `Invoke()` the right way? I am not sure if I should be using `BeginInvoke()` and `EndInvoke` instead? The event contains no date and is simply used as a `signal` that the async job can do things already.

The code in `Class B` where the `ChangeOccurred` event is invoked is synchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke`. Those methods just call `Invoke` on a thread pool thread.

Using `myEvent?.Invoke()` is an appropriate way of raising the event, which (synchronously) sets the `AsyncManualResetEvent`. The fact that there's an asynchronous *listener* on the `AsyncManualResetEvent` doesn't matter.

On a side note, the latest (v5 preview) version of AsyncEx includes `PauseToken` 
/ `PauseTokenSource` types which are really just a simple wrapper around `AsyncManualResetEvent`, but might make the intent of the code a bit clearer.